# What is $\mathbb{Z}^2/\mathbb{Z}v_1+\mathbb{Z}v_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $v_1 = (2,3)^T, v_2 = (4,5)^T \in \mathbb{Z}^2$. Let $H =\mathbb{Z}v_1+\mathbb{Z}v_2$. What is the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}^2/H$? Describe it.

To start with, I consider an easier version: $\mathbb{Z}^2 / \mathbb{Z} v$ where $v = (3,5)^T$. I see that we can define $h: \mathbb{Z}^2 \to  \mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus\mathbb{Z}_5$ by $h(x,y) = (x \mod 3, y \mod 5)$. But I am having trouble with this question.

I naively considered the following. For any vector $(a,0)^T$, it is either in $(0,0)^T + H$ or in $(1,0)^T + H$. For any vector $(0,b)^T$, it is either in $(0,0)^T + H$ of $(0,1)^T + H$ since $\gcd(3,5) = 1$. But what about any general $(a,b)^T$?

Comment: [See if you find this helpful](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586353/how-to-recognize-a-finitely-generated-abelian-group-as-a-product-of-cyclic-group/1604950#1604950).  Also [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form).

Comment: @SpamIAm That should work. Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to post your solution once you figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $2v_1-v_2=e_2$ and so $H=\mathbb Z 2e_1 + \mathbb Z e_2$. This makes it easy to compute $\mathbb Z^2 / H$.

This corresponds to the following reduction to Smith normal form:
$$
\pmatrix{ 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5}
\to
\pmatrix{ 2 & \hphantom{-} 3 \\ 0 & -1}
\to
\pmatrix{ 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}
$$