# Generators of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^n $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, galois-theory

A subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ has a generator, the g.c.d of its elements.

***Is there such a result for a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ ?*** (= Can we always find m generators ?)

Context: I'm reading a book on Galois's theory and it says: if $M = \mathbb{Z}[e^{i\pi/n}]$, M is a finite $\mathbb{Z}$ module and so $M \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is a finite $\mathbb{Z}$ module too (and hence equals $\mathbb{Z}$). I can prove the part "finite module / ring on integers $\implies$ equals $\mathbb{Z}$" but Im stuck for the other part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\zeta = e^{2\pi i /n}$.  Then $\zeta$ is a root of the polynomial $\frac{x^n-1}{x-1} = x^n + x^{n-1} + \cdots + x + 1$.  This shows that $\zeta$ is [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element) over $\mathbb{Z}$, which is equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ being a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module (see the section [equivalent definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element#Equivalent_definitions) in the above link).  Thus $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is an integral extension of $\mathbb{Z}$, so $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is also an integral extension of $\mathbb{Z}$.  But since $\mathbb{Z}$ is integrally closed, then every element of $\mathbb{Q}$ that is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ already belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$.  Since $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta] \cap \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ and every element of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$, then we must have $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta] \cap \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why it is phrased like this in the book
Out of curiosity do you have an answer to the "subgroup of $Z^n$ question?

Comment: Not all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ are cyclic for $n \geq 2$, so it's not possible to find a single generator in general.  For instance, consider the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ generated by $(2,0)$ and $(0,3)$.  You can find a "nice" set of generators by computing the [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) of a matrix: see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586353/how-to-recognize-a-finitely-generated-abelian-group-as-a-product-of-cyclic-group) for example.

Comment: (sorry I meant a base of generators, editing the question)